# How to access session variable in SSRS (SQL Server 2012)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I want to access the session or viewstate variables in `SSRS 2012` reports just like we access in `c#`.

`Session["user"]`

I want to access like this in `SSRS` report.

I want to include the user who is logged in when the report is generated.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can we access it in custom code in `SSRS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code behind, you could copy the desired data at a report parameter.

```
    // Copy the session username to a report param called "CurrentUser".
    ReportParameter userParam = new ReportParameter("CurrentUser", Session["user"]);

    // add the parameter to the report
    reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { userParam });
```

And then add your parameter to the report as you would any other parameter.
See example at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx

Comment: Is this applicable to Oracle Database?

Comment: The code the I wrote, was specifically for Reporting which is not tied to a specific database.

Comment: Thank you.. I got the idea but not the full answer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

In the report itself you can reference the user running the report with `User!UserID`.

See [Built-in Globals and Users References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx).

**Edit after comment:**

Since it seems that you have no internal reference to the user running the report, your best option might be to pass the user reference in with a **Hidden Parameter**.

From Books Online:

> You can hide the parameter on the parameter input area of the
>   published report, yet set values for it on a report URL or in a
>   subscription definition.

So in this case it would mean that the parameter would never be visible to users, but you could set it programmatically.

You could pass a string based on `Session["user"]`, or however you're managing user IDs outside the report, to the report then display/manipulate this parameter as required in the report.

Comment: I saw that sir but I don't use Windows Authentication, and by the way I use Oracle as Database if that would help.

Comment: How are users accessing the report? Report Manager website? ReportViewer control in web application? ReportViewer control in desktop application?

Comment: When you say you don't use Windows Authentication are you talking about the Data Source or the actual security to access the report; they are distinct.

Comment: ReportViewer in web application.

Comment: OK, what about the second question?

Comment: Both the data source or the actual security to access.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a lot of common data you could store the session data in a temporary table in the database.  You update this session data table before you run the report.  Then you can just access this data like any other table in the report, specifing the just the user ID as a parameter.